# Is it okay to stop my repair on my mysql database if it's not showing in processlist?

Tags: mysql

I started a repair on a table in my database that seems to still be running.

```
mysql> repair table dicore_search_index;
[empty line]
```

It's just been sitting there like that since i started it about an hour ago.

If i open another sql shell and run `show processlist` all i see is this:

```
mysql> show processlist
+-------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Id    | User        | Host               | db               | Command | Time | State | Info             | Rows_sent | Rows_examined |
+-------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 77772 | dmginc71_gf | 159.89.140.1:59577 | dmginc71_diforum | Query   |    0 | init  | show processlist |         0 |             0 |
+-------+-------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

Which leads me to believe it's not running, am i okay to cancel it?

Comment: How fat is thas table? is it accessible from another shell session?

Answer (score 0):

Its odd that your `SHOW PROCESSLIST` doesn't include the `REPAIR TABLE`. This suggests its in some form of hung state. Check with a new connection and `SHOW PROCESSLIST` again. If it also doesn't show the `REPAIR TABLE`, I'd restart the mysqld service and try again.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the table?  If it under perhaps a million rows, it should have finished by now.

Your second connection -- was it via the same user or via 'root'?  If neither, then you cannot see the `REPAIR` due to permissions.

You said "blank line" as if that is unexpected?  It makes me think the repair has not even started?  Use Ctrl-C on that terminal.

`REPAIR` rebuilds the table.  In doing so, it makes a copy, then at the last moment plays games with `RENAME TABLE`.  This makes it 'safe' to kill -- with the exception that there could be a bogus file left behind.  It will be named something like `#sql...`.